# IP with area locations?

Tags: java, ip

how are you guys?
i want to get a file with all of the IP addresses and area locations for these addresses for the middle east.
i have googled it but still can't get my potential file.
can any one help me ???

Comment: Where's the programming question?

Comment: @simchona i liked your original comment better ;)

Comment: @sdolgy I realized I was just telling the OP to do something he already claimed to.

Answer (score 1):

IP Addresses:

1. Identify the countries you classify as being in the middle east.
2. Identify all of the internet service providers in each of those countries
3. Query the netblock assignments for each of those service providers to get a list of IPv4 blocks

Addresses:

1. Identify the countries you classify as being in the middle east.
2. Go to wikipedia and query each country to get a list of the border co-ordinates
3. Create a java application that takes the co-ordinates and outputs them into a "file" in the format you require.

Alternately, you can use the [MaxMind](http://www.maxmind.com/app/products) related products to obtain the information you require.  In the comments, it was mentioned that you want a *free* solution and that you have disqualified [Maxmind](http://www.maxmind.com/app/products) because they only have non-free options.  If you spend some time looking on the site, and researching this topic, You'll find that they have *free* options:

1. [GeoLite Country](http://www.maxmind.com/app/geolitecountry)
2. [GeoLite City](http://www.maxmind.com/app/geolitecity)
3. [GeoLite ASN](http://www.maxmind.com/app/asnum)
4. [GeoLite World Cities](http://www.maxmind.com/app/worldcities)
5. [GeoLite Postal Codes](http://www.maxmind.com/app/postalcode)

If this still isn't easy enough for you, here's a fantastic link that shows **all** of the available *free* databases that [MaxMind](http://www.maxmind.com/app/products) provide:

- [MaxMind GeoIP Databases](http://geolite.maxmind.com/download/geoip/database/) and the most important part, The [MaxMind GeoIP License](http://geolite.maxmind.com/download/geoip/database/LICENSE.txt)

Comment: can you give more explanation please ??

Comment: +1 not my question but I thought this answer was clear and concise without catering to "give me teh codez"

Comment: sorry for that , but I'm new in this sector ?

Comment: @eng what don't you understand? I have no experience in this sector and the answer made sense to me. I'm sure sdolgy is willing to help you if you can articulate what's not making sense

Comment: @sdolgy firstly, thank you for your answer and awareness
i have gone to the MaxMind website, but it has a commercial products that you need to pay to get it.
i was asking if you can give me some free links to get this mapped file, or any other way that i don't know.
thank you again.

Comment: 1.  You didn't specify you want something **free**.  2.  They have a `free` GeoLite offering (if you actually spent time on the website): http://www.maxmind.com/app/geoip_country